# If a cell in an incoming row from a Google Form has a certain value, then run a script function

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs

I want to take new entries in a Google Sheet (coming in from a Google Form), and run a certain trigger on them depending on the response in column B. I have written out the code (which sends the information to a Google Doc template), and established a trigger, but it doesn't differentiate the data in column B.

Here's a very generic version of what I'm working on: [Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfDNMhDyM74P8APeVUZ7LwWqqEFxxCDYiVQr3BmzUA37HKhrQ/viewform), [Workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j6yrrvljOGWbemcuSy5w-l7nZN5BBEp1T_YGAA7AG1c/edit?usp=sharing), and [Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BxK26Yim0-nAVQW5FcQ59q3Uxe2qm9EhClLE1thSdMU/edit).

And here's the code I've got:

```
function Bob(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var name = e.values[1];
  var awesome = e.values[2];
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1BxK26Yim0-nAVQW5FcQ59q3Uxe2qm9EhClLE1thSdMU'); 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('149gm5Voa3tthmv66cF5kJmf3bf2zj-VA')
  
  var copy = file.makeCopy(name, folder); 
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', timestamp); 
  body.replaceText('{{Name}}', name);  
  body.replaceText('{{Awesome}}', awesome); 
  
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

So essentially, if column B says Bob, then the trigger will kick in and the function will operate. If it says Joe, then a separate trigger would run a different function (that I have yet to set up, but assume it'd be little more than a copy-paste job). My guess is that it'd just take a few lines in the form of an if-statement before my function runs, but I'm very new at this.

Thanks

Comment: What are your trigger settings for function `Bob(e)`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition by using an if statement, i.e.,

```
function Bob(e){
  if(e.values[1] === 'Bob'){
    // Add here what you want you function does when the corresponding cell of Column B is equal to "Bob"
  }
}
```